# How to save streaming data from On-Premise Hadoop cluster to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, hortonworks-data-platform

We are running a real time streaming application on Hortonworks using Kafka and Spark Streaming in On-Premise cluster setup.

We have a requirement where we need to push some event triggered data from Spark Streaming Or Kafka to save on S3 file system of AWS.

Any pointers around this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can save using the s3a:// scheme and the Hadoop fileSystem API, e.g something a bit like

`val fs = FileSystem.get("s3a://bucket1/dir", sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
val out = fs.create("dest/mydata", true)
out.write(" whatever, I forget the API for OutputStreams, it takes byte arrays really")
out.close()`

It can be a bit tricky setting up the classpath, but everything should be set up in HDP for this. More precisely, if it isn't, I get to field the support calls :)